I want to get an output of below program as 122.00, when I make input 50, but it is like 122.0 I need 2 digit output in this case
def temp_converter(_value):

    fahrenheit = (_value*9.00/5.00)+32.00
    fahrenheit = round(fahrenheit,2)
    print(f"Temparature in fahrenheit : {fahrenheit}")
celcius = float(input(": "))

temp_converter(celcius)

output is like:
122.0
but I want 122.00.

That's not actually the correct answer.  You are only giving one significant digit for the input value, and the result cannot be more accurate than the input.  The correct answer is "122" with no decimals at all.

This question is similar to: Python print a float with a given number of digits. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

So the thing here is you have to define how many decimal places you want in your output.
Let me correct your code.
def temp_converter(_value):
    fahrenheit = (_value * 9.00 / 5.00 )+32.00
    fahrenheit = round(fahrenheit, 2)
    print(f"Temperature in fahrenheit: {fahrenheit:.2f}")
celcius = float(input("Enter temperature in Celsius: "))
temp_converter(celcius)

So as you can see I have entered ":.2f" at the end of the varible Fahrenheit in the print statement to define the no.of decimals I want in the output.
And Do not forget the indentations specially in Python

If you use the format specification ":.2f" then use of round(_,2) is redundant

def temp_converter(_value):
    fahrenheit = (_value * 9.00 / 5.00) + 32.00
    fahrenheit = f"{fahrenheit:.2f}"  # Format to 2 decimal places
    print(f"Temperature in fahrenheit: {fahrenheit}")
celcius = float(input("Enter temperature in Celsius: "))
temp_converter(celcius)


Please be careful with your indentation, especially with Python, where it is critical.  I've fixed it this time.  Also, rather than just shove code out there, a proper answer would explain what you have done that solves the original problem.  You have no explanation at all.

thanks, i got the difference between round() and .2f
